# assigning attributes to tags while pasting from word in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do i assign attributes to tags while pasting from word in ckeditor?I want to add certain style attributes to my paragraph tags while pasting content from a word document into ckeditor.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: The basic problem is the increased line spacing between paragraphs compared to that present in my original word document. I know that this is due to paragraph tags which are being inserted in between paragraphs. If i can somehow assign margin attributes to the paragraph tags, i can counter the increased line spacing.

Answer (score 0):

whatabout hooking in to the on paste event. You should be able to add cleaning there, just make sure that the word cleaning is done first. Have a look here:
http://codesel.blogspot.se/2012/08/ckeditor-remove-html-tags-from-pasted.html